# SVG elements not drawn on correct place in firefox browser

Tags: firefox, svg

I am trying to draw a rectangle using SVG editor but the cursor position is not correct while drawing the rectangle.

This problem occurring only in Firefox browser. In other browser it is working fine.

Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the svg and the problem.

Comment: Are you using an old version of svg-edit? If so you should use the latest version of that software.

Comment: Thanks for the consideration of your time. I got the solution. :)